# Proxy problem using testcontainers and spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

I try to write an spring-boot integration test using the docker-compose module of [testcontainers](https://testcontainers.org). I get the following exception on 
startup:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException:
{"message":"Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host"}
```

I already tried to add our company http proxy using with Env but it doesn't work.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FtpExportIntegrationTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static DockerComposeContainer environment =
        new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/docker-compose.yml"))
            .withExposedService("search-kafka", 9092)
            .withEnv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080")
            .withEnv("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080")
            .withEnv("http_proxy", "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080")
            .withEnv("https_proxy", "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it in your Docker daemon settings, not container's.